# Counting the number of times a specific hour appears in a column after extraction in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, po

after using the extract function to extract an hour value from a timestamp in postgresql, how can I count the number of times each value appears? I'm trying to produce the number of calls coming into a helpdesk based on time of day. So I need to be able to count the number that came in at 2pm, 3pm, 4pm and so on. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please update with the schema you are querying and the SQL you have already tried.

Comment: select count(extract(hour from timestamp_column)), extract(hour from timestamp_column) from your_table group by extract(hour from timestamp_column)

Comment: Thank you Fahad that is exactly what I was looking for.